# Add temporary active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a method for adding likes to a page

**blade.php**

```
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=heart" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button">
<div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
  {{ $article->like_heart }}
</div>

<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=finger" class="comments-sub-header__item like-button">
<div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
  {{ $article->like_finger }}
</div>
```

Adding a like on click

**js**

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
  });

  $('.like-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: href,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function() {
        window.location.reload();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Next, I made an `active` class with styles, and when I click on the like to the class `class="comments-sub-header__item like-button"` this class should be added `active`

But there is one more thing, my likes are stored in cookies, and 24 hours after clicking we can put a new like, that is, the `active` class should also be disabled after 24 hours

This is how I implemented it adding a like to cookies

```
Route::post('article/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@postLike');
```

```
public function postLike($id, Request $request) {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        if(!$article){
            return abort(404);
        }

        $type = $request->input('type');
      
        if ($article->hasLikedToday($type)) {
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'You have already liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                ]);
        }
    
        $cookie = $article->setLikeCookie($type);
      
        $article->increment("like_{$type}");
    
        return response()
            ->json([
                'message' => 'Liked the Article '.$article->id.' with '.$type.'.',
                'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
            ])
            ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

```
public function hasLikedToday(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        if (!array_key_exists($this->id, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$this->id])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$this->id][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public function setLikeCookie(string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        $articleLikes[$this->id][$type] = now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
```

As I understand it, all this should be done in `js`, but I still do not really understand it, so I ask for a hint

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish and what problems are you having? And why are you using cookies instead of storing this in a database?

Comment: @miken32 cookies are needed so that you can re-put like, but only after a certain time, namely 24 hours

Comment: @miken32 The question is that I need to add a function to my js code, that when clicked, the active class is added in `class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count"`, and it must also act for 24 hours

Comment: @miken32 how to add a class is understandable, but how to make it work 24 hours after clicking, that's the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply share a variable in the view where you show the "like" buttons somewhere in your controller:

```
// Your controller
public function show(Request $request, $postId)
{
    $post = Post::find($postId);
    $hasLikedToday = $post->hasLikedToday('heart');

    return view('your.view.file', [
        'article' => $article,
        'hasLikedToday' => $hasLikedToday, // share this variable to check if you've liked today
    ]);
}
```

After sending the `hasLikedToday` variable to your blade where the like buttons are defined, you simply check if the variable is `true`, if so, show the active class. Now every time you refresh that page, it will check if the active class must be shown, no need for javascript to do that.

```
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}?type=heart" class=" ... {{ $hasLikedToday ? 'active' : '' }}">
<div class="comments-sub-header__item-icon-count">
    {{ $article->like_heart }}
</div>
```

Comment: indeed, this is a very good variation, thanks a lot)